# How to set GDAL environment variables to the directory containing EPSG csv files in Python?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, gis

The following code results in errors quoted below.
I am running virtual environment using Ubuntu from Microsoft store and bash.exe.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fp = "zipfiles/IND_adm0.shp"
map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)

map_df.plot()
```

Errors:

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv files.
ERROR 6: No translation for an empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known.
```

Comment: do you have a projection file?  IND_adm0.shp ?

Comment: @user1269942 Yes sir, I do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ensure a solid install of gdal?  https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/

I notice that geopandas does not require it(as per its requirements file).

But I also see that fiona, one of the geopandas dependencies, refers to gdal but it's not explicitly in their requirements files (for pip).

"pip install gdal" may solve your issue.